# jQuery not working in jade. Documnet.ready function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, pug

Tried different intendations but the jQuery part is still not working.
**PS** : **The jQuery lib is already included this document is extended.**

```
extends home
mixin print(x,y)
 if x < y
  .column=x
 else
  .column

mixin rooms(n,num,a,b,c,d)
 while n < num
  .row(value=n++)
  +print(n,a)
  +print(n,b)
  +print(n,c)
  +print(n,d)

block content

  div(id="tabs")
  .row
   .column
    a(href="#tab1" onclick="open(this.href)") Ground Floor
   .column
    a(href="#tab2" onclick="open(this.href)") Ist Floor
   .column
    a(href="#tab3" onclick="open(this.href)") IInd Floor

  div(id="tab1")
   +rooms(100,111,111,104,111,111) 
  div(id="tab2") 
   +rooms(200,217,217,211,214,211)
  div(id="tab3")
   +rooms(300,317,317,311,314,311)

script(src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js')
script.
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#tab1').hide();
  $('#tab2').hide();
  $('#tab3').hide();   
 });
```

1.**jQuery isn't hiding the div it is asked to hide**

2.NO error in console.

Comment: Don't compare the Jade source code to the effect you see in the browser. Look at the HTML you are generating from Jade. Is it as you expect? Then debug it. Look at the developer tools in your browser. Are there errors on the Console? If you add tests like `console.log($('#tab1').length);`, what results do you get?

Comment: not well versed in jade but looks like extra `.` after `script`. As mentioned above see what it produces in browser

Comment: @charlietfl — That `.` is required: http://jade-lang.com/reference/plain-text/

Comment: The html generated is as expected no errors in console. Just the jQuery isn't working.

Comment: @virattara — Then all else being equal, it should work. There isn't enough information in your question to determine what the problem is. (And it would be better to show us the HTML that doesn't work than the Jade since you have said that the HTML you are getting is the HTML you want, so it can't be a problem with the Jade).

Comment: Minor point but would be more efficient to hide those elements with css instead of script. Would be no FOUC (flash of unstyed content)

Comment: In jade you set an element id using `#` like this: `div#tabs`, `div#tab1`... In case of `div` you can ommit the word `div` and use the ID directly (`#tabs`, `#tab1`, `#tab2`) as you did with classes (`.row`, `.column`).

Comment: jquery should be before the document.ready script and there should be no error on console. you may share a screenshot of console tab of inspector

Comment: @DeepakSharma — The OP has stated that there are no errors in the console. If jQuery wasn't loaded before the script then there would be an error.

Comment: The only problem in jQuery is not working its .hide() function isn't hiding  the divisions it is asked to hide.

Comment: Can you post your "rooms" jade mixin?

Comment: @virattara — You've already said that. You haven't provided enough code for us to reproduce the problem. You need to supply a [MCVE]

Comment: @Quentin added the mixin code too thats all the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay finally when you have a file which is extended you keep your js code in the parent file because keeping at the end of the extended document causes it to be inherited by some tag.

Answer (score 0):

> The html generated is as expected

I copied the Jade into [this online converter](http://jade-lang.com/).

The end of the output looked like this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#tab1').hide();
   $('#tab2').hide();
   $('#tab3').hide();   
</script>});
```

You missed out the indent before `});` so it was placed **outside** the script element.

> no errors in console

This generated the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

When I corrected that error, it successfully hid the elements:

```html
<div id="tabs"></div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column"><a href="#tab1" onclick="open(this.href)">Ground Floor</a></div>
  <div class="column"><a href="#tab2" onclick="open(this.href)">Ist Floor</a></div>
  <div class="column"><a href="#tab3" onclick="open(this.href)">IInd Floor</a></div>
</div>
<div id="tab1">
  <div value="100" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">101</div>
  <div class="column">101</div>
  <div class="column">101</div>
  <div class="column">101</div>
  <div value="101" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">102</div>
  <div class="column">102</div>
  <div class="column">102</div>
  <div class="column">102</div>
  <div value="102" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">103</div>
  <div class="column">103</div>
  <div class="column">103</div>
  <div class="column">103</div>
  <div value="103" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">104</div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column">104</div>
  <div class="column">104</div>
  <div value="104" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">105</div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column">105</div>
  <div class="column">105</div>
  <div value="105" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">106</div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column">106</div>
  <div class="column">106</div>
  <div value="106" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">107</div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column">107</div>
  <div class="column">107</div>
  <div value="107" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">108</div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column">108</div>
  <div class="column">108</div>
  <div value="108" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">109</div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column">109</div>
  <div class="column">109</div>
  <div value="109" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">110</div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column">110</div>
  <div class="column">110</div>
  <div value="110" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
</div>
<div id="tab2"> 
  <div value="200" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">201</div>
  <div class="column">201</div>
  <div class="column">201</div>
  <div class="column">201</div>
  <div value="201" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">202</div>
  <div class="column">202</div>
  <div class="column">202</div>
  <div class="column">202</div>
  <div value="202" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">203</div>
  <div class="column">203</div>
  <div class="column">203</div>
  <div class="column">203</div>
  <div value="203" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">204</div>
  <div class="column">204</div>
  <div class="column">204</div>
  <div class="column">204</div>
  <div value="204" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">205</div>
  <div class="column">205</div>
  <div class="column">205</div>
  <div class="column">205</div>
  <div value="205" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">206</div>
  <div class="column">206</div>
  <div class="column">206</div>
  <div class="column">206</div>
  <div value="206" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">207</div>
  <div class="column">207</div>
  <div class="column">207</div>
  <div class="column">207</div>
  <div value="207" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">208</div>
  <div class="column">208</div>
  <div class="column">208</div>
  <div class="column">208</div>
  <div value="208" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">209</div>
  <div class="column">209</div>
  <div class="column">209</div>
  <div class="column">209</div>
  <div value="209" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">210</div>
  <div class="column">210</div>
  <div class="column">210</div>
  <div class="column">210</div>
  <div value="210" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">211</div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column">211</div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div value="211" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">212</div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column">212</div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div value="212" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">213</div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column">213</div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div value="213" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">214</div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div value="214" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">215</div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div value="215" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">216</div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div value="216" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
</div>
<div id="tab3">
  <div value="300" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">301</div>
  <div class="column">301</div>
  <div class="column">301</div>
  <div class="column">301</div>
  <div value="301" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">302</div>
  <div class="column">302</div>
  <div class="column">302</div>
  <div class="column">302</div>
  <div value="302" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">303</div>
  <div class="column">303</div>
  <div class="column">303</div>
  <div class="column">303</div>
  <div value="303" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">304</div>
  <div class="column">304</div>
  <div class="column">304</div>
  <div class="column">304</div>
  <div value="304" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">305</div>
  <div class="column">305</div>
  <div class="column">305</div>
  <div class="column">305</div>
  <div value="305" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">306</div>
  <div class="column">306</div>
  <div class="column">306</div>
  <div class="column">306</div>
  <div value="306" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">307</div>
  <div class="column">307</div>
  <div class="column">307</div>
  <div class="column">307</div>
  <div value="307" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">308</div>
  <div class="column">308</div>
  <div class="column">308</div>
  <div class="column">308</div>
  <div value="308" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">309</div>
  <div class="column">309</div>
  <div class="column">309</div>
  <div class="column">309</div>
  <div value="309" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">310</div>
  <div class="column">310</div>
  <div class="column">310</div>
  <div class="column">310</div>
  <div value="310" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">311</div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column">311</div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div value="311" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">312</div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column">312</div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div value="312" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">313</div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column">313</div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div value="313" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">314</div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div value="314" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">315</div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div value="315" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column">316</div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div value="316" class="row"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#tab1').hide();
   $('#tab2').hide();
   $('#tab3').hide();   
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your dedication is exceptional sir but seems like I missed out a space bar hit while copying the code. The }); was intended properly in the original document. Apologies for that and mine code is still not running. I'm using Firefox is there a possibility it creating a problem?

Comment: @virattara — No, the live demo in this answer works fine in Firefox.

Comment: On my server it isn't working tried the jade converter all is good there.

Comment: @virattara — Then something about the HTML on your server is different to the HTML generated from the Jade you put in the question. Which brings us back to needing a real [MCVE].

Comment: Okay working on it. By the way are these three words always in your cache. You are quick at mentioning them.

Comment: `[MCVE]` is a stackoverflow macro.

Comment: and these make asking a question seriously a tough task. Some reforms must be considered like minimal is contradicting the rest 3.

Answer (score -1):

try writing # with ids

```
div(id="tabs")
  .row
   .column
    a(href="#tab1" onclick="open(this.href)") Ground Floor
   .column
    a(href="#tab2" onclick="open(this.href)") Ist Floor
   .column
    a(href="#tab3" onclick="open(this.href)") IInd Floor

  #tab1 rooms(100,111,111,104,111,111) 
  #tab2 rooms(200,217,217,211,214,211)
  #tab3 rooms(300,317,317,311,314,311)
```

Comment: That makes no difference to the output.